# https to remote website and wss to my local desktop app

Tags: c#, https, websocket, ssl-certificate, self-signed

Before asking, I explain my env.

### dev environment

1. a web site with https.

As you see, I used websocket API and works well in ws not wss.

```
websocket.ws = new WebSocket("wss://localthost:port");
```

2. a local desktop program(c#) which supports websocket (library I used : https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp)

To support wss, I used sample code below, and made pfx file based on the link (http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html)

```
   var wssv = new WebSocketServer (5963, true);
   wssv.SslConfiguration.ServerCertificate =
                 new X509Certificate2 ("/path/to/cert.pfx", "password for cert.pfx");
```

### Usage scenario

Based on the data from website, message is sent to local desktop program.

### Trial

As you see, I used self signed certificate, but it gives certificate related error.

So I tried adding my self-signed root CA to chrome browser, but it did not work.

### Question

Can anyone give me advice to support localhost secure websocket in localhost or any certificate criteria?

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902547/websocket-ssl-connection, rejectUnauthorized option might be for node not client javascript.

Comment: same issue here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748446/secure-websocket-with-localhost-certificate#